# How can I highlight XML on the command line?

Tags: command-line, xml, syntax-highlighting

How can I highlight XML from stdin (e.g. piped from `xmllint --format`) to stdout?

I know how to get highlighting working in `nano` and `view`, but is there something that just outputs to stdout and exits?

What I'd link to do is just type something like

```
xmllint --format xmlfile.xml | some-highlighter
```

or maybe, for big files

```
xmllint --format xmlfile.xml | some-highlighter | less
```

and get pretty output.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Supercat](http://supercat.nosredna.net/index.html) and [grcat](http://korpus.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html) (grc) can do piped syntax highlighting. You'll probably have to make or find configuration files for XML. They are both available in the Ubuntu repositories as well as at the links provided.

[Pygmentize](http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/) has XML highlighting included. It's available as "python-pygments" in the Ubuntu repositories or by using `easy_install Pygments`.

```
xmllint --format xmlfile.xml | pygmentize -l xml | less
```

Comment: Pygmentize did the trick for me, although, at least on OS X, I had to give it the option `-O encoding=UTF-8` to make it work on xmllint's output. Thanks!

Comment: If you're like me and annoyed by pygmentize complaining when you exit less without consuming all its output (Broken pipe), pipe through buffer (`apt-get install buffer`). E.g. `xmllint --format foo.xml |pygmentize -g |buffer |less -r`

Comment: In more modern Ubuntu, I used `sudo apt install python-pygments` to install it.

Answer (score 15):

This is how you do it using [GNU source-highlight](https://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/) and less:

```
source-highlight -i /tmp/foo.xml -f esc | less -r
```

Comment: From stdin, it's just `source-highlight -s xml -f esc`

Comment: Although actually, I'm finding `esc256` produces prettier output than `esc`

Comment: Note, this won't format the XML, and if your XML is all on one line, it will cause `source-highlight` to run very slowly. It is probably parsing the input line by line. This command gave me good, fast results: `xmllint --format - < input.xml | source-highlight -f esc -s xml | less -F`

Comment: @Winny, that is awesome, thank you. One minor note: I got it working with `less -r` (as stated in the answer) instead of `less -F`.

Answer (score 8):

I found [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.html) in Homebrew for OSX, and I'm sure it's available in the Ubuntu repository. It does highlighting and output to a number of formats, including terminal output.

Comment: `pbpaste|xmllint --format -|highlight --out-format=ansi --syntax=xml` did the trick for me. (I could argue about highlight's color choices, though.)

Answer (score 7):

I use `bat`:

```
xmllint --format - | bat -pP
```

`-p` removes all decoration (line numbers, etc.), `-P` disables the pager. **Update**: use `-pp` with newer versions of bat.

**bat**: https://github.com/sharkdp/bat

Comment: For `bat` 0.12.1  I cannot use `-P`, but I can use `--paging=never` instead.  (The error message was: `error: Found argument '-P' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context`)

Comment: With [Debian's *bat* package](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/bat) (`sudo apt install bat`), the command is `batcat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my cli tool xmq (https://libxmq.org) to pretty print and syntax highlight XML and HTML. Note that it renders the XML/HTML/JSON in the XMQ format which is easier to read and edit. There is however a 1-1 mapping between XMQ and XML. The tool is very useful for analyzing large xml and html files.

The xmq tool also includes a pager for the terminal:
`xmq xmlfile.xml page`

The tool can also render into a temporary html file which is automatically viewed in your default browser:
`xmq xmlfile.xml browse`

It picks the color scheme from your terminals background color (light or dark), but you can override it:

`XMQ_BG=dark xmq xmlfile.xml browse`

`XMQ_BG=light xmq xmlfile.xml browse`

It works in a pipeline as well:
`curl https://slashdot.org | xmq delete //script delete //style page`

Apart from deleting xpath matched nodes, there are other commands to convert to and from xmq/xml/html/json and apply transformations to the content.